# Firebase Query startAt()

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

[image: my database view]

I am using a query and having some trouble. I want retrieve value from 5th to 10th. I try to use startAt () the query just doesn't get anything.

```
public void read(){

    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("values").orderByChild("timestamp").startAt(5).endAt(10);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Value upload = data.getValue(Value.class);
                mUploads.add(upload);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Loading Quote failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Tl;DR: Firebase database queries are cursor based, and not offset based.**

When you call `startAt()` you have to pass in the **value** of the timestamp you want to start returning results at. You can't pass in offsets, as you are trying to do now.

---

You current code:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    .getReference("values")
    .orderByChild("timestamp")
    .startAt(5)
    .endAt(10);
```

Tells the database to:

1. Find the node called `values` under the root.
2. Order each child node by its `timestamp` value.
3. Then find a child node with value `5` and start returning results from there.
4. Stop returning results once it finds a child node with value `10`.

As you can probably see, this won't give you any results, since none of your child nodes have a timestamp value between 5 and 10.

---

As said: Firebase queries are cursor based, meaning they work on knowing something about the node to start at. While many databases paginate based on offsets, Firebase doesn't and you'll need to know the timestamp value of the node to start at.

For example, if you want to start at the node you have opened in your screenshot, and then return the next 5 results, you'd do:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    .getReference("values")
    .orderByChild("timestamp")
    .startAt(-1590413110563)
    .limitToFirst(5);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have already tried this,  timestamp will not always be the same, there will be renewed data

Comment: If you can have multiple child nodes with the same value for their `timestamp` property, you can pass in the **key** of the node as a second child into `startAt`: `.startAt(-1590413110563, "-M8B-Xjvb2WMqmMC-p3-")`.